# PM2 Throws Module Not Found Error After Server Boot

Tags: node.js, pm2

My project throws the error "Cannot find module 'index.js'" every time pm2 starts the app after server boot (I don't import index.js anywhere). This problem does not happen when I start it manually with "pm2 start". My main is dist/index in package.json and ecosystem.config.js

I didn't try anything. I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.